# DNA sequence not divisible by 3 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sequence, dna-sequence

I am trying to get the list of codons and aminoacids of the input dna sequence. For this I created a function which verifies if the sequence is divisible by 3 or not.
When the function is not divisible by 3 then, I want to get a random codon from the dictionaty, using as precedent the last one or two nucleotides of the sequence and with the random tool get get the final codon.

This is the code that I have so far.

```
seq = "GAGCGTCTGCTCCGTGTATAAGCCACGTCGGAGCT"
def codons(seq):
    codon_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
        codon_list.append(seq[i:i+3])
    return codon_list
print("Codons: ")
print (codons(seq))

genetic_code = {
       "GCG" :"A","GCA" :"A","GCT" :"A","GCC" :"A",
       "AGG" :"R","AGA" :"R","CGG" :"R", "CGA" :"R","CGT" :"R","CGC" :"R",
       "AAT" :"N","AAC" :"N",
       "GAT" :"D", "GAC":"D", "TGT" :"C","TGC" :"C",
       "TGA" :"*","TAG" :"*","TAA" :"*", # * Stop codon
       "CAG" :"Q","CAA" :"Q",
       "GAG" :"E","GAA" :"E",
       "GGG" :"G","GGA" :"G","GGT" :"G","GGC" :"G",
       "CAT" :"H","CAC" :"H",
       "ATA" :"I","ATT" :"I","ATC" :"I",
       "TTG" :"L","TTA" :"L","CTG" : "L","CTA" :"L","CTT" :"L","CTC" :"L",
       "AAG" :"K","AAA" :"K",
       "ATG" :"M" , # Start codon
       "TTT" :"F" ,"TTC" :"F" ,
       "CCG" :"P" ,"CCA" :"P" ,"CCT" :"P" ,"CCC" :"P" ,
       "AGT" :"S" ,"AGC" :"S" ,"TCG" :"S" ,"TCA" :"S" ,"TCT" :"S" ,"TCC" :"S" ,
       "ACG" :"T" ,"ACA" :"T" ,"ACT" :"T" ,"ACC" :"T" ,
       "TGG" :"W" ,
       "TAT" :"Y" ,"TAC" :"Y" ,
       "GTG" :"V" ,"GTA" :"V" ,"GTT" :"V" ,"GTC" :"V" 
  }

nn_seq = []
def tranlastion(seq):
    for dna in seq:
        protein_seq = ""
        if len(dna) % 3 != 0:
            for j in range(0, len(dna), 3):
                codon_r = genetic_code[dna[j:j +3]]
                protein_seq += codon_r
            return genetic_code[random.choice(codon_r)]
            
            #print("Choose a random codon")
    for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):
        n_codon = genetic_code[dna[i:i +3]]
        protein_seq += n_codon
        nn_seq.append(protein_seq)
tranlastion(seq)
```

ISSUE:
Once I run the code the output is: **KeyError: 'G'**

I don't understand where is the error with the key and how could I fix this in order to get the previously mentioned.

Thank you for advices.

Comment: Is this a follow-up to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73680484/1639625

Comment: The error is that for the last segment, `dna[j:j +3]` may be just one or two chars, and thus is not in the table. See the other answer for how to select a random protein with that prefix in that case.

Comment: @tobias_k yes, I've  checked your answer in the previous question. Thank you. However, if I implement the prefix, then I should do it for every codon. Because every sequence will have different end. That's why I wanted to use the random  and avoid  using a prefix. If you've another option, will be wondeful. I've been trying to solve it without success.